# Displaying firebase data onto React table

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, reactfire

I'm having trouble displaying data from my firebase database into a table using React.
How would I map through a transaction consisting of:
payee, amount, date, category onto a table? So when the user enters a transaction, it is mapped onto the table. For example, when entering a transaction

```
const transaction = {
  payee: Wal-mart, 
  date: 01-29-2022,
  category: groceries,
  amount: 120,
  From Account: Checking
```

I'm trying to use Semantic UI to build a table so when a transaction is entered it will populate into a table for viewing. I tried building the table body but it wont allow me to map through each transaction value as a row. Is there a more efficient way of dynamically entering this into a table or a framework that can make this more simple?

For example,
[image]

```
import AddTransaction from "./AddTransaction";

import { useCollection } from "../../hooks/useCollection";

//styles
import "./Transactions.css";
import { Table } from "semantic-ui-react";

export default function Transactions() {
  const { documents, error } = useCollection("transactions");

  return (
    <div className='transactions'>
      <div className='transaction-title'>
        <h1>Transactions</h1>
      </div>
      <AddTransaction />
      <div className='transactions-list'>
        {error && <p className='error'>{error}</p>}
        {documents && (
          <>
            <Table celled>
              <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Payee</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Date</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Category</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Amount</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Notes</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>From Account</Table.HeaderCell>
                </Table.Row>
                <Table.Body>
                  <Table.Row>
                    {documents.map((doc) => (
                      <>
                        <Table.Cell>{doc.transaction}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{doc.date}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{doc.amount}</Table.Cell>
                      </>
                    ))}
                  </Table.Row>
                </Table.Body>
              </Table.Header>
            </Table>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which error you're running into, so it's possible I've missed something, but here are the issues I've noticed:

1. Based on what you wrote above, I'm assuming each transaction maps to a single document with the fields `date`, `payee`, etc at the root level. Assuming that's the case, there is no `transaction` field so (`<Table.Cell>{doc.transaction}</Table.Cell>`) doesn't make sense.
2. Even if there *were* a transaction object on doc, you're trying to output an object directly to the DOM
   (`<Table.Cell>{doc.transaction}</Table.Cell>`). Objects aren't valid children in React, so that will throw an error.
3. You're trying to use the document directly, but you need to access its data via the `data()` method that Firebase includes on each doc. `doc` also has other information on it like `id` and `createTime`, hence needing to use the `data()` method to get *your* data.

You're looking for something like this:

```
<Table.Row>
    {documents.map((doc) => (
        <>
            <Table.Cell>{doc.data().date}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{doc.data().payee}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{doc.data().category}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{doc.data().amount}</Table.Cell>
        </>
    ))}
</Table.Row>
```